# Constant Service variable Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a service in angular, where I stored an array called `array_item` obtained from my api call and in the component I declared 2 variables called `var_1` and `var_2` where both have the same value which I've obtained from the service

i.e: `var_1 = this.service.array_item` && `var_2 = this.service.array_item`

I'm listing it in my HTML as lists of 2 DIVs but when I update the value in the list_1 it changes the array item value in service which automatically changes my array item data in list_2. I don't want list 2 to get changed I want it to be constant. Suggestions or solutions are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to you assign same value to both variable or you can call it **shallow copy.** All you need to do clone value using **deep clone**. Simplest way to do this is:

```
var_1 = this.service.array_item
var_2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.service.array_item))

OR

var_2 = [...this.service.array_item]

OR

var_2 = this.service.array_item.slice()
```

For more reference about deep copy vs shallow copy you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: This JSON approach is performance intensive. So you can look in to the this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript

Comment: yes it slow but it is one of the way, otherwise we can use spread operator

Comment: This json parse and json stringify works fine for me, but not the slice and spread method. Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this behavior is obvious because JavaScript is **pass by reference**. So you can solve the problem by keeping 2 other copies of the original array in component level.

Copying can be done as explained in this [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Then component code will be like,

```
var_1 = this.service.array_item.copy() // Implement copy function
var_2 = this.service.array_item.copy() // Implement copy function
```

Comment: Hello as I've mentioned in the answer you have to implement the copy functionality. You can refer the Reference link in my answer to do that